# Files "exist" long after being deleted

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7 x64. Now, there's this bunch of three JPEGs that I deleted permanently from my computer a long time ago. There are no references to these files anywhere in my system - I have tried changing Explorer options to show all hidden and system files, as well as using the command prompt to see every file in the said directory. Everything shows that the files don't exist.

*However,* when I conduct a search by extension (*.jpg) in the said directory, these three files appear out of nowhere. I can't see their thumbnails or open them, presumably because they don't exist. However, the search result shows the original size of the files. I can't even "delete" them because they don't exist.

[image: screenshot]

How do I get rid of these files permanently?

Comment: sounds like your filesystem may be corrupted. try booting into recovery console and performing a `chkdsk /f` to remove any orphaned $MSFT references to your files. Its also likely that the files remain indexed even after delete, so you may want to rebuild your search indexes: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/17880-index-rebuild.html

Comment: Looks like a time-consuming process for such a trivial issue :(

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache index file for Windows Search?

Comment: @antikbd; of course it is up to you as to whether you feel the problem is sufficiently worth the fix.

Comment: Yes sir I understand. I just wish Windows wouldn't play up like this. Do you reckon this problem will be solved if I reinstall Windows?

Comment: depends on which of the two it is, and whether you elect to format the disk while installing. if its in the indexes, definitely, but if its in the MSFT, no. either way, it seems like rebuilding your indexes would take the least time, chkdsk in the middle, and a rebuild as the longest, so unless you were already contemplating a rebuild, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: If they only show up when you search for them, then do as Ramhound suggests and [rebuild the Windows search index](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/17880-index-rebuild.html).

Comment: Alright. I am rebuilding the index first to see how it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue through a rebuilding of the search index. Thanks guys!